# not all characters are printed java

Tags: java, printing, thermal-printer

I am trying to print to a **POS** thermal printer. I am successful but the words I am trying to print are not printed even if there are still space left for the other characters
for example I print `"hello world"` in the paper it only appears as `"hello w"` even if there is still space left on the paper to print the rest of the characters in the string.

Additional info: I use the defaultPage for my `PageFormat`.

```
 PageFormat pf = job.defaultPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a custom PageFormat with your own paper dimensions? Something like this:

```
PageFormat pf = new PageFormat();
Paper paper = new Paper();
paper.setSize(width, height);
paper.setImageableArea(startX, startY, width, height);
pf.setPaper(paper);
```

The `setSize(...)` method takes dimensions in units of 1/72 of an inch. I'm guessing the `setImageableArea()` method uses the same units, but the [documentation for PageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/print/PageFormat.html) is not entirely clear.

I've no idea why there's no option to use millimetres as the unit instead of the bizarre "1/72 of an inch". And I'm not sure how you would configure the PageFormat if you use a roll of paper rather than individual sheets.

Comment: I am getting confused with the measurement the java uses, if for example my paper width is only 3inches, what will be my parameter for setSize() and setImageableArewa? thx

Comment: Well, one whole inch is 72 lots of "1/72 of an inch". So three inches is 3 * 72 = 216. So try setting the width to 216. Again, why this class has used such a bizarre unit of measurement, I don't know. Possibly it's some printing convention of old.

Comment: Ow ok ill give it a try and post the results, ill be getting the height based on the number of lines of the receipt

Comment: Sir I tried adjusting the paper size to paper.setSize(300,200), pageFormat.setPaper(paper), then do a int x = pageFormat.getImageableX(); and int y = pageForemat.getImageableY(); I always get x=72.00 and y=80.00 no matter what my paper size is... when I try to print the result in the paper is "Hello wor" instead of "Hello world" then I tried to force x = 70 the result when I print is "ello worl" instead of "Hello World"